# mail decode using base64 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, utf-8, decode

I am trying to implement decode mail

--001a11419e22edc789053c4ccb1b
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
This is known to all
--001a11419e22edc789053c4ccb1b
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

This is known to all

--001a11419e22edc789053c4ccb1b--

how can i decode the html formate in UTF-8
i am also trying decode

```
 require 'base64'
 def decode(x)
  y = Base64.decode64(x)
 d = y.force_encoding('UTF-8')
return d
```

but error is 
   invalid byte sequence in UTF-8 
when i use only Base64.decode64(x)
then it showing the output..
�����uӟ6۽�ٽ9��xݯ= ��z{Sʗ�{�V���Z�ǭQ1|~��j
what is the reason behind it?

Comment: Your example text is not Base64 encoded. Do you try to decode this plain text?

Comment: i am decoding ........ Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8; format=flowed; delsp=yes
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

U29tZW9uZSBoYXMgeW91ciBwYXNzd29yZA0KDQoNCg0KSGkgRGViYXNpc2gsDQpTb21lb25lIGp1

aWwgY2FuJ3QgcmVjZWl2ZSByZXBsaWVzLiBGb3IgbW9yZSBpbmZvc
--94eb2c110582272b2b053c143a89

Comment: Sorry still I don't unterstand what you decode. `U29tZW9uZSBoYXMgeW91ciBwYXNzd29yZA0KDQoNCg0KSGkgRGViYXNpc2gs‌​DQpTb21lb25lIGp1 aWwgY2FuJ3QgcmVjZWl2ZSByZXBsaWVzLiBGb3IgbW9yZSBpbmZvc` is only the base64 encoded part. So you can only decode this part and not the whole string. Do you send the whole string to `Base64.decode64` ? In this case you will get an invalid result.

Comment: I am already decoded  y = Base64.decode64('U29tZW9uZSBoYXMgeW91ciBwYXNzd29yZA0KDQoNCg0KSGkgRGViYXNpc2gsDQpTb21lb25lIGp1') but problem is when i all string which is store in a variable (x) that shows an error..above...how can i decode whole string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't parse an email only with `Base64.decode64`. Only a small part of some emails is base64 encoded. You have to extract this parts and after this you can use `Base64.decode64` to decode the extracted parts.

If you want to parse an email you can do it "by hand" or use existing gem's like for instance https://github.com/mikel/mail